# Compaq Armada 1500 Laptop Won't Boot

Tags: laptop, memory, bios, compaq-laptop, windows-95

I have a Compaq Armada 1500 (specifically 1575D) laptop. When I turn it on it goes from 1 to 32768 KB (it scans the kilobytes of memory I think) OK then beeps 2 times and says 162-System Options Not Set. I replaced the BIOS battery. I need to get into the BIOS somehow right? How would I do that (some kind of key or a floppy)?

Specs

-166 MHz Pentium MMX

-3 1/4 GB HDD IBM Travelstar

-16MB of RAM (I believe)

-CD Drive doesn't open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That machine is from 20 years ago.

Keyboard has nothing to do with memory. But the BIOS will recognize it.

Older machines like that usually used F10 to get into BIOS.  Start and repeatedly press F10. See if BIOS loads.

You can use a bootable USB (Linux most likely) to see if you can start and then see the disk. Just starting will tell you things about what might be working.

Motherboard may have a problem. Disk may have a problem.

Memory can be tested with a bootable USB Key.  memtest86.exe   https://www.memtest86.com/

Please see this Wiki Article for information about this computer.

[Compaq Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compaq_Armada)

If the machine will not start it may be dead.

Comment: Uh what do you mean? KB stands for kilobytes. Thanks for trying to help though. Wikipedia doesn't tell me much about my model and I read the manual for it. I'll try the USB stuff, but I don't think it can get there because the BIOS settings are not set. It won't let you continue without setting them.

Comment: Post was not clear to me so yes KB abbreviation stands for Kilobytes (memory). See the machine starts from a bootable USB key or original CD. You need to start it and if it won't start, it may be dead.

Comment: Okay I will try

Comment: F1 does not work.

Comment: The machine may be dead. Look up Armada doc to see if (a) you can boot from an external device and (b) how to get into BIOS. 20 years old means some research on your part.

Comment: Yes the BIOS is not stored on the motherboard. You either need to press F10 if it's on the hard drive or use a floppy with it on it.

Comment: The BIOS is stored on its own chip.  That is normal.

Comment: No I believe there is NO bios chip. NO bios at all. It has to be installed on a partition on the hard drive or booted from a floppy diskette. I know it sounds weird but search for Compaq Armada 1500 manual to see for yourself.

Comment: That is different than the older machines I have seen.  But this one is a very long time ago.

Comment: Yes again thanks for your help.